# Does Android do data backup automatically in the case no backup requests?

Tags: android, backup, database-backups, android-backup-service

I am writing my first Android application that using local Sqlite database. I want to implement database backup onto Google cloud so Android can restore the database whenever end-user re-install the application.

As my understanding. Whenever data changed, developers need to call "**BackupManager.dataChanged()**" to let request a backup.

**My question is:** What happen if developers don't call "BackupManager.dataChanged()" when data changed? Does Android will do a backup automatically/regularly EVEN there is no request backup from developers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read this and concluded that "to do a backup", dataChanged() must be called :

```
 "Each time that your application data changes and you want to perform a backup, 
 you must request a backup operation by calling dataChanged()."
```

The restore process is automatic when the app is re installed.

```
"Android automatically performs a restore operation when your application is 
installed and there exists backup data associated with the user."
```

Both these sentences are 'as it is copy pasted' from this link : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Comment: Thank you! I read this page before but still came up that question. I guess you are right.